# Unable to insert data into sqlite db after setup deployment C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, installation

[This is the screenshot of my target folder after deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3fRy.png)I am facing a strange problem. I am using a SQLite db with winforms and C#. Once I create a setup file and install it to a target machine (to the x86 program files folder), and I run the app, I am only able to read from the db file but I am not able to insert new rows. If I just copy my application files to any other system and try, it works perfectly but not through setup and deployment. Can't understand what the problem is.. Any help please?
Thanks,
Sarin

Comment: Got the problem... The issue is that there is no write permission for the db file when it is deployed via setup file. How can we overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

I just used InstallForge to create the setup file and set the installation path to C:\Foldername and the issue is solved. Only if I say program files folder, it gets the readonly setting.